# How do we know when Azure App Service 'Swap with preview' is complete?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've noticed that when i use ['Swap with preview' on Azure App Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/04/azure-app-service-swap-with-preview/), the portal says "Success" immediately.. suggesting the operation has completed.

But actually, it hasn't..if i refresh my site, it appears nothing has happened, then some time after (30 secs? 1 minute?) the swap with preview operation commences. I can tell, because my website is recycling (slow to respond).

So my question is - since the 'Swap with preview' operation seems to be a background operation, and the success message merely indicates the operation has been 'queued', how do we know when it's done? (done = slot has the destination slot's configuration applied, restarted, and ready for 'complete swap')

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the **Activity Log**. The swap with preview will appear as *Slotswap* operation:

[image]

Source: [monitor-swap-progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing#monitor-swap-progress)

Comment: Thanks. How do we know when it's done though? Which sub-operation of "Slotswap" is the one we need to wait for?

Comment: You have to wait for the top level slotswap, not a sub-operation